# Mass mailing feature

Tags: xdocreport

Is there a way to iterate through a contact list and build a single document file containing my template file for each contact. I'm looking for a way to realize a kind of mass mailing (publipostage).
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you use and the format of your template you might consider : 
https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport

If you use java you can easily take a docx or odt template and generate PDFs or HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the response, in fact i already use xdocreport and my question was about the mail merge feature in xDocReport, i mean how from 1 template file  and a datasource i can generate many documents and save them in a single file just like mail merge feature in word or libreoffice.